# When will blogger fix this know issue and why still sell domains

Tags: blogger

I bought a domain for my blog through Google (which uses GoDaddy to actually get the domains), but it seems like there are some problems. I can't get stevehinch.blogspot.com to redirect to www.thailandsinvestor.com.

I notice this has been a know issue with Blogger since 2012 yet they still sell domains to people like me knowing there is a issue that has not be fixed
How do I redirect my blog to my new url

Comment: Can you be more specific? What have you already tried? There is a how-to here: http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/static.py?hl=en&ts=1233381&page=ts.cs

Comment: I have tried everything that blogger have suggested, all to no avail. Blogger states the blog should automatically redirect to the new url but it has not and no matter what I have tried nothing works

Answer (score 1):

The known-issue was [resolved back in September](http://knownissues.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/custom-domain-security.html), and the ability to buy domains, which has been disabled, was restored after that.

There is a new issue (not yet acknowledged as a known-issue by Blogger) with accessing your domain administrator account - but there is [a solution for](http://blogging.nitecruzr.net/2012/12/after-using-buy-domain-blog-owners.html) this this documented by one of the Blogger Product-form top-contrubutors.

The WebApplications people may not like me for saying this, but IMHO you are better of posting your query in the Blogger Product-forum:  the contributors there have the detailed knowledge of current issues, and will help with diagnosing the specific problems with your particular domain setup.